# Failed to read external resource while querying on json dataset in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-serde

I created external table, then loading json file format into table.I have added json jar into hive.

```
hive> create database if not exists databasename;

hive> use databasename;

hive> create external table if not exists table-name(col1 string)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde';

hive> load data inpath '/user/file1.json' into table-name;
```

Here after I am getting error "select * from table-name"

Error "error while processing statement: Failed to read external resource hdfs://nameservice1/user/filepath"

Comment: Can you paste the error message also?

Comment: Is it multi line json or single line json ?

Comment: It's multi line json @DeepanRam

Comment: "error while processing statement: Failed to read external resource hdfs://nameservice1/user/filepath" @NageshSinghChauhan

Comment: Hive requires files in a format of one JSON objects per line. Also, not clear why you're using an external table without giving a location

Comment: Thank you! Got where I am wrong. @cricket_007